# Puzzling over my routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, devise

I am writing a Rails app that I partially inherited. There is a snippet of code in the routes.rb that I'm trying to puzzle out and can't find anything in the documentation.

```
  authenticate :users do 
    resources :authentications
  end
```

What does this do and why is it needed here? I'd never seen the `authenticate` used in this context before. There are resources called users and authentications in the file, and I am using Devise+OmniAuth for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [here in the Devise Docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method), it allows you to add authentication at the router level rather than at the application level(aka controllers, essentially).